# Convert textbox to float

Tags: c#, textbox, double

I've been looking for different ways to do it, but I still get the same error:

What I've tried:

```
float e = (float)Convert.ToDouble(e_textBox.Text);
bool valid = float.TryParse(e_textBox.Text.ToString(), out e);
```

And I get this error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'System.EventArgs'
```

am I doing that wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `float.TryParse` is a good way. ***If*** for some reason you want to use the `Convert` class, do `Convert.ToSingle` as it gives you a `float` right away, instead of creating a `Double` which you narrow into a `Single`. But as I said, prefer `Parse` or `TryParse` methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing your code lives inside an event handler. One of the parameters to your handle will be `EventArgs e`:

```
public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float e = (float)Convert.ToDouble(e_textBox.Text);
    bool valid = float.TryParse(e_textBox.Text.ToString(), out e);
}
```

You just need to come up with a new variable name (or rename the parameter to something other than e):

```
public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eargs)
{
    float e = (float)Convert.ToDouble(e_textBox.Text);
    bool valid = float.TryParse(e_textBox.Text.ToString(), out e);
}
```

Comment: I've just get it. Thank u!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Not that much of a stretch, when his error says `System.EventArgs` because the default variable name for EventArgs as a parameter is `e`. :P Although, no idea why he didn't get an error from creating the `float e`.